# CSS animation with jQuery Function has Delay Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a problem regarding the duration and responsiveness to click of the CSS transform animation. The problem is that upon first clicking the toggle, the animation responds to clicks and can be stopped mid-way allowing it to switch back and forth. However, on the way out, which is the second click after the completion of the first round of the jQuery function, the animation must reach its full duration before it can be activated again. How can I make it that so that the animation responds to clicks (able to be cancelled mid-way) both first time and second time executing the function? Help is appreciated, thank you.

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="circle1"><li class="products"><a href="#">Products</a></li></div>
</div> 

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<a><img id="ring" src="New Assets/ring5.png" alt=""></a>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

```css
.circle1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 400px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(2000px);
}    
#ring {
    background-size: contain;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $circle1 = $('.circle1');
    $('#ring').on("click", function() {
        if ($circle1.css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2000)') {
            $circle1.css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 400)');
        } else {
            $circle1.css('transform','matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2000)');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML has some spaces missing between the tag names and attributes, but other than that it should work fine. Can you include a full sample of your HTML including the `.circle` element

Comment: Yes I will include. Those are some accidental spaces in the HTML when I added it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works... Can you send all files ?

Create new file with that and try (it's your code) :

```
<style>
.circle1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(250px);
}

#ring {
    background-size: contain;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
</style>


<a>
    <img id="ring" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/06/29/12/038FBB710000044D-3143037-image-a-30_1435578285388.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<div class="circle1">
    <ul>
        <liclass="products">
            <ahref="#">Products</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var $circle1 = $('.circle1');
  $('#ring').on("click", function() {

    if ($circle1.css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 250)') {
      $circle1.css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)');
    }
    else {
      $circle1.css('transform','matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 250)');
    };
  });
});
</script>
```

## EDIT (try this) :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var $circle1 = $('.circle1');
  $('#ring').click(click);

  function click()
  {
    // Get this
    var t = $(this);
    // Disable click event
    $(this).off('click');
    // After 1500ms set reset click
    setTimeout(function(){ t.click(click); }, 1500);

    if($circle1.css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 250)')
    {
      $circle1.css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)');
    }
    else
    {
      $circle1.css('transform','matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 250)');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes it does, but notice when you click it the first time and immediately click it after wards before the picture reaches the top, it cancels the animation half way and reverses back to its original location.  However, if you let the picture run its full animation and then on the way back, the animation cannot be cancelled mid-way.

Comment: For me it's work, what is your navigator ? (for try)

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: No need to be! Thank you, this code I think waits for the animation to complete before moving on to the next function. However, is there a way move the element with the toggle without any delay? For example, reversing the animation while mid-way. Thanks again.

Comment: Anyways, I found another solution for my problem. By using the (.open) class and a bit of CSS tweaking I can also bring back and forth the element.

Comment: Yes ! Change this line "setTimeout(function(){ t.click(click); }, 1500);". After 1,5 seconds, you can reclick for toggle, so after finish. But if you change 1500 per 250 (or other delay) : after 0,25 seconds, you can toggle event.